# C# checking listview checkbox depending upon the items matching the array

Tags: c#, winforms

I m new in C# programming. I m running into a problem. the problem is that. I have listview control in a winform application. Listview has checkboxes. first Column of a listview contains the IDs that comes from database.

I also have an array which I have written like this

```
string selectCompany = "1,2,3,4";
companies = selectCompany.Split(new String[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

All I want to do is if any value in the first column of listview is in above array, I need to check that row.
How can this be achieved? 
Any help will highly be appreciated.

**Update**
The code I have so far is

```
string selectCompany = "1,2,3,4";
companies = selectCompany.Split(new String[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (DataRow row in company.Rows)
{
    string[] rows = { row["type_id"].ToString(), row["type_name"].ToString()};
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(rows);

    lstCompanyType.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    if (companies.Length > 0)
    {
        if (companies.Contains(row["type_id"]))
        {
            //i m JUST NOT SURE HOW TO CHECK LISTVIEW ITEMS THAT MATCHES THE ARRAY
        }
    }
    serialno++;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I have expected this answer. A common answer to all problems, all programming languages and the answer everybody knows. I m not asking for whole bunch of code. Just a hint will be well enough for me, I said i m fairly new in C# programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (companies.Contains(row["type_id"])){
  listViewItem.Checked = true;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, that is not the way you define an array in C#.
the correct way would be

```
string[] array = {"1", "2", "3", etc.}
```

You need to get all the Items in the ListView then iterate through the listview item.

```
foreach(ListViewItem lvi in ListView.Items)
{
    //for your "array" use
    if(lvi.SubItems["key"].ToString() == selectCompany.Contains(lvi.SubItems["key"].ToString()))
    {
        lvi.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

This will set the checked item of the listview item

EDIT:
Try this

```
string selectCompany = "1,2,3,4";
companies = selectCompany.Split(new String[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (DataRow row in company.Rows)
{
    string[] rows = { row["type_id"].ToString(), row["type_name"].ToString()};
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(rows);
    if(selectCompany.Contains(row["type_id"].ToString()))
    {
        listViewItem.Checked = true;
    }
    lstCompanyType.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    if (companies.Length > 0)
    {
        if (companies.Contains(row["type_id"]))
        {
            //i m JUST NOT SURE HOW TO CHECK LISTVIEW ITEMS THAT MATCHES THE ARRAY
        }
    }
    serialno++;
}
```

Comment: I have to use this loop inside my `DataRow` foreach loop??

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, a listview does not contain a DataRow, unless you are looping through your dataset. Then a different approach than the one i provided is required

Comment: Yes I m looping through dataset

Comment: @King-King gave this answer as well. I just put it inside your code

Comment: I got error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'`  on your if condition.  `selectCompany.Contains` returns boolean isn't it?? The left side operand is string and right side is boolean. Moreover, the right side always return either  `1` or '0'. Even if there is no error, the code seems not to work because, this will checkbox the listview rows if `lvi.SubItems["key"].ToString()` equals 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
((CheckBox)row.FindControl("YourCheckBoxIDHere")).Checked = true;
```

Is the code fragment that is missing in your code.